# How to convert an integer to date?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, timer

I created a count down timer like this:

[image]

I set manuel values for startTime

```
 var options = {
    stepTime: 60,

    format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
    startTime: "01:12:32:55",
    digitImages: 6,
    digitWidth: 53,
    digitHeight: 77,
    image: "digits.png"
};
```

I have lblDay,lblHours,lblMinutes,LblSeconds on page.

I can get TotalHours column from SQL.How can I convert value of TotalHours  to like this :

```
lbDays:27

lblHours:2

lblMinutes:34

lblSeconds:08




int TotalHours = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][11]);

//int TotalHours =664
```

and How can I set value of labels to startTime

Comment: So which is it, Java, C# or Javascript?

Comment: This is at least unclear..

Comment: Sorry.I want to convert to day,hours,minutes,seconds in c# and send to javascript for startTime

Comment: `int TotalHours` is this the difference between the current date and some future date? What about the difference in minutes and seconds?

Comment: given that a `TimeSpan` has `TotalDays`, `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds`, this should be fairly easy, no?

Comment: difference from now to  (now +int totalhours)

Comment: @user3107343 why bother with "now to (now + int totalhours)" ? that is always going to be just "{totalhours} hours", which you can do directly with `TimeSpan.FromHours`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int totalHours = 664; // example from question
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(totalHours); // or similar
int days = (int)ts.TotalDays,
    hours = ts.Hours,
    // note the next will always be zero
    // since we init in an integer
    // number of hours
    minutes = ts.Minutes,
    seconds = ts.Seconds;
```